# Reference existing record or add new record for many-to-many relationship in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship as follows:

```
Table1
ID (int) | Name (string)

Table2
ID (int) | Data (string)

Table1_2
Table1ID (int) | Table2ID (int)
```

I would like to do the following in Entity Framework:

Given a `List<Table1>`, look to see if any records in Table1 that match; if so, reference them; if not, add them and reference them. For example, something like:

```
public void InsertOrReferenceExisting(string data, List<Table1> table1References)
{
    var myEntities = new MyEntities();
    var table1Entities = new EntityCollection<Table1>();
    foreach(var row in table1References)
    {
            var existing = myEntities.Table1.Where(x => x.Name == row.Name);
            if (existing.Count() > 0)
            {
                // reference existing row in Table1
            }
            else
            {
                // add new row to Table1
            }
    }
    myEntities.Table2.AddObject(new Table2
        {
            Data = data,
            Table1s = table1Entities
        });
    myEntities.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Why are you trying to add `table1Entities` to Table2?

Comment: To clarify: your end goal is to save the new Table1 objects, the new Table2 object, and put a row in your Table1_2 table for the new Table2 record and each Table1 record passed (new or not) in. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
public void InsertOrReferenceExisting(string data, List<Table1> table1References)
{
    using (var myEntities = new MyEntities())
    {
        var tbl2 = myEntities.Table2.CreateObject();
        tbl2.Data = data;
        myEntities.Table2.AddObject(tbl2);
        foreach (var row in table1References)
        {
            var tbl1 = myEntities.Table1.Where(x => x.Name == row.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (tbl1 == null)
            {
                tbl1 = myEntities.Table1.CreateObject();
                tbl1.Name = row.Name;
            }

            tbl2.Table1.Add(tbl1);
        }

        myEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Note that this solution doesn't allow for multiple records in Table1 that have the same value in the Name column. You should probably enforce that with a unique constraint on the database level.